# how to count the depth of an XML file - DOM

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing, sax, jdom

i want to count the depth of an XML file like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"  encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <country> -----> Level 1
   <name> France </name> ----> Level 2
   <city> Paris </city>
   <region>
     <name> Nord-Pas De Calais </name> ---> Level 3
     <population> 3996 </population>
     <city> Lille </city>
   </region>
   <region>

   </region>
  </country>
```

Comment: So what has been your approach so far? What have you tried that is not working?

Comment: what is your desired result? to find the deepest depth of the document? or just a general method to count the amount of nested child nodes. in my experience it's not usually that important what the depth of the nodes are, since they are usually found by node name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this and customize as per ur needs... Using DOM parser

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = db.parse("country.xml");
    Element elem = dom.getDocumentElement();        
    int level = 1;
    System.out.println(elem.getNodeName() + "--->" + level);
    NodeList nl = elem.getChildNodes();
    displayLevel(nl,level);
}

/**
 * Recursive function to go through the nodes to display the level.
 * @param nl
 * @param level
 */
private static void displayLevel(NodeList nl, int level) {      
    level++;        
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = nl.item(i);
            System.out.println(n.getNodeName() + "--->" + level);               
            displayLevel(n.getChildNodes(), level);             
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: how can i display the max depth , in my example , the max depth is 3

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for a tree traversal

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

specifically you can do this in two ways depth or breadth..

there are multiple java technologies that will do this.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/TraversetheDOMtreeusingTreeWalker.htm

what specifically are you trying to do

Answer (score 1):

It is all about relationships. In JDOM, the relationship you want is the number of parent elements.

On the other hand, if all you want is the level of the elements then raw SAX parsing would be faster and all sorts of better.

Just in case this is homework, I'll just point in the right direction....

with JDOM you can use the getParentElement() function on Content, and loop on that until there ar eno more parents. If you count each loop you will have the level....

with DOM you also have a getParentNode()

with SAX you can increment and decrement a 'level' in the startElement and endElement methods.